# Box to appear fully around equation

Tags: equations, box

In the code below, I am only getting a box around part of my equation like this:

[image]

How do I get the box to appear around the full equation?  Thanks!

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\fbox{
$
  \zeta\nearrow
  \underset
     {\mathrlap{\displaystyle\Searrow\text{ overshoot}\searrow}}
     {\mathrlap{\Rightarrow\text{P.M.} \nearrow}}
$
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a phantom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\fbox{
$
  \zeta\nearrow
  \underset
     {\mathrlap{\displaystyle\Searrow\text{ overshoot}\searrow}}
     {\mathrlap{\Rightarrow\text{P.M.} \nearrow}}
\hphantom{\Searrow\text{ overshoot}\searrow}$
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to the use of `\mathrlap`. Here is another approach, based on the `eqparbox` package and a simple `\boxed` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqlmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1][l]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

$ \boxed{%
 \zeta\nearrow \underset {\eqlmathbox{\displaystyle\Searrow\text{ overshoot}\searrow}}%
     {\eqlmathbox{\Rightarrow\text{P.M.} \nearrow}}
}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution.  However, when I tried your code, the double arrows are not aligned as you have in your graphic. Could this be due to the fact that I am using XeLaTeX?

Comment: You have to compile twice, because the package has to measure both `\eqmakebox`es.